# Adding columns from a SQL Server select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simplifying the issue I am having, I am trying to select additional columns
in a select query. Here is how I can try to explain:

Table **Names**

```
code    name
--------------
T001    John
T001    Mary
```

Table **Places**

```
city    state   zip
--------------------
NewJ     NJ    0001
NewY     NY    0002
```

I am trying to have a `select` that will show this:

```
code  name  city  state   zip  name2  city2  state2 zip2
---------------------------------------------------------
T001  John  NewJ    NJ   0001   Mary  NewY     NY   0002
```

I tried using:

```
select
    a.code,
    a.name, a.city, a.state, a.zip,
    b.name as name2,
    b.city as city2,
    b.state as state2,
    b.zip as zip2
from 
    Names a
left join 
    (select name, city, state, zip 
     from Places b) b on b.code = a.code
```

Get an error saying that it can't find code `b.code`.

Is there a better way to do this using SQL Server?

Comment: b.zip = a.code i suppose

Comment: How are these two tables related?

Comment: It could be related by an ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
  a.code,
  a.name,
  a.city,
  a.state,
  a.zip,
  b.name as name2,
  b.city as city2,
  b.state as state2,
  b.zip as zip2
FROM
  Names a
  LEFT JOIN Places b on b.zip = a.code
```

Comment: You should change the aliases to `n` and `p` so they are not arbtirary letters.

Comment: I think I will need to find another way to do this, may be with nested select statements that would allow selecting several columns.